# ftp_connect function not working to connect with localhost in MAC

Tags: ftp, php8

I have tried so many things but `ftp_connect` and `ftp_ssl_connect` are not working in my development instance.

I am using ***MAC*** and ***PHP8.1***, I am trying to connect to localhost with the below simple script:

```
<?php
    
    // Connect to FTP server
    $ftp_server = "localhost";
    
    // Establish ftp connection
    $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 22, 10)
        or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    
    if($ftp_connection) {
        echo "Successfully connected to the ftp server!";
        
        // Closing connection
        ftp_close($ftp_connection);
    }
    
    ?>
```

This is always returning `bool(false)` instead of the `FTP/Connection` object. I have also checked the Firewall, it is disabled on my local machine.

Do we need to configure anything in order to work with it?

Thanks

Comment: "localhost" should be the server itself. Is there an FTP server running on that server? Can you anonymously FTP into that server?  From your command line try ``ftp localhost`` (you may need to use the webserver user since the PHP script is running as that user)... You may need to use ``ftp_login``

Comment: Thanks, @MagePalExtensions for your reply. I tried `ftp localhost`, it is working and also I am able to connect through FTP client FileZilla. Please help me I am still unable to connect via `ftp_connect`.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280014/how-to-get-the-ftp-error-when-using-php